# grouping logical expressions

Tags: python, expression

How do I tell Python I want to do the following:

```
if cond1 and (not cond2 or not cond2)
```

I want the expressions in the parenthesis to execute first and then feed the result to and.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like most languages, python evaluates expressions left-to-right, so you simply need to put them in the order that you want them to be evaluated:

```
if (not cond2 or not cond3) and cond1
```

Comment: It is worth noting that if `(not cond2 or not cond3)` evaluates to `False` then `cond1` will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of **operator precedence** as described in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). As you can see in the table below (from highest to lowest precedence), parenthesized expression are the first ones to be executed.

Operator precedence is a common concept in most programming languages.

Moreover, what @Hooked is referring to is called **short circuit evaluation**.

[image]